# How to consistently start Vim's command line to make a mapping work in any mode?

Tags: vim, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping, vimrc

I try to normalize access to Vim's command line mode from any other mode in order to simplify my actual mappings. For example to make the `<f6>` key work from anywhere I define the following mappings:

```
noremap <script> <unique> <silent> <f6> <sid>:echomsg 'Hello World!'<cr>
noremap! <script> <unique> <silent> <f6> <sid>:echomsg 'Hello World!'<cr>
```

The above mappings remap to the `<sid>:` key mapping given below before they get down to work:

```
noremap <unique> <expr> <sid>: <sid>StartCmdLineMode()
noremap! <unique> <expr> <sid>: <sid>StartCmdLineMode()
function! s:StartCmdLineMode()
  let a=mode()
  if a ==# 'n' 
    return ':'
  " Type <c-v><c-v> to insert ^V. 
  elseif a =~ '[vV^V]'
    return ":\<c-u>"
  elseif a ==# 'no'
    return "\<c-c>:"
  elseif a ==# 'i' 
    return "\<c-o>:"
  elseif a ==# 'c' 
    let b=getcmdtype()
    if b ==# ':' 
      return "\<c-e>\<c-u>"
    else
      return "\<c-c>:"
    endif
  else
    return ''
  endif
endfunction
```

Is there a staightforward way instead of my obfuscated approach?

Answer (score 2):

When does the following not work?

```
nnoremap <F6> <ESC><ESC>:command<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I came up with the following approach:

```
noremap <script> <unique> <SID><\O> <Nop>
inoremap <script> <unique> <SID><\O> <C-\><C-O><SID><\O>
cnoremap <script> <unique> <SID><\O> <C-\><C-N><SID><\O>
noremap <script> <unique> <SID><\N> <Nop>
noremap! <script> <unique> <SID><\N> <C-\><C-N><SID><\N>
```

For each Vim mode the `<SID><\O>` key sequence is mapped in order to appropriately escape (e.g. `<C-\><C-O>`) from Vim's current mode (e.g. insert-mode) to its normal mode. The right hand side of each mapping ends in its left hand side (e.g. `<SID><\O>`) in order to recursively try to escape again. The script-local (`<script>`, `<SID>`) recursion stops as soon the last escape key sequence reaches Vim's normal mode in which the `<SID><\O>` key sequence is mapped to nothing (`<Nop>`).

Likewise the `<SID><\N>` key sequence is mapped to not only escape once (`<SID><\O>`) from e.g. insert-mode before returning back but permanently stay in normal-mode.

With the help of the above definitions I mapped the `<F1>` and `<S-F1>` function keys as follows:

```
noremap <script> <unique> <expr> <F1> <SID>ToggleHelp(':<C-U>help', '<SID>')
noremap! <script> <unique> <expr> <F1> <SID>ToggleHelp(':<C-U>help', '<SID>')
noremap <script> <unique> <expr> <S-F1> <SID>ToggleHelp(':<C-U>helpgrep', '<SID>')
noremap! <script> <unique> <expr> <S-F1> <SID>ToggleHelp(':<C-U>helpgrep', '<SID>')
function! s:ToggleHelp(cmd, sid)
  ToggleVar s:HelpCwordOn
  let a=s:HelpCwordOn ? '<cword>' : '<cWORD>'
  return a:sid . '<\O>' . a:cmd . ' ' . expand(a) . ' '
endfunction
command! -bang -nargs=+ ToggleVar call <SID>ToggleVar(<bang>0, <f-args>)
function! s:ToggleVar(bang, var)
  let {a:var}=exists(a:var) ? !{a:var} : !a:bang
endfunction
```

Instead of having the `<F1>` key simply open Vim's help in a new window, it starts the `:help` command with the inner word (`<cword>`) under the cursor. By consecutively pressing the `<F1>` key, one switches to the outer word (`<cWORD>`) and toggels back again.

The 4 mappings from the use case above could also be defined as follows in order to not repeat yourself; i.e. keeping it "dry":

```
let a='noremap'
let b='<script> <unique> <expr>'
let c='<F1>'
let d='<S-F1>'
let e='<SID>ToggleHelp('':<C-U>help'
let f='grep'
let g=''', ''<SID>'')'
let h=b . ' ' . c . ' ' . e . g
let i=b . ' ' . d . ' ' . e . f . g
exec a . ' ' . h
exec a . '! ' . h
exec a . ' ' . i
exec a . '! ' . i
```